# Probability of picking the same basket.

Tags: probability

If there are 8 baskets of which five of them have chocolates. A kid is now allowed to pick any 5 baskets. What is the probability that the kid chooses the same five baskets which have chocolates in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{8\choose5}$ since there are 8 choose 5 ways of choosing five baskets and only one gives the desired outcome.

Comment: I took a bigger route of P(a) and (b) and.... so on. This was much easier. Thanks !